# Pillow rotate not quite right

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

It is hard to explain so please look at the image. It appears to rotate the data within the image but not the image itself.

original:

[image]

Rotated -90:

[image]

```
    block = scene.read_block()
    image = PILImage.fromarray(block)
    image_rotate = image.rotate(-90)
    buf = BytesIO()
    image_rotate.save(buf, "JPEG", quality=90)        
    return buf.getvalue()
```

The viewport didn't rotate only the image inside.

Thanks

Comment: please share a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use expand=True to change the size

```
image.rotate(-90, expand=True)
```

it is in the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate)

Comment: Thanks, Obviously I started at the top and stopped at the first reference.